# script cannot connect to Mysql server Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql5.5

Mysql server seems working properly and running also i can connect to the database via ssh command, here's the my.cnf file directives:

```
[mysqld]
#port=3306
datadir=/home/mysql
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
#port=3306
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

im trying to install a script it says :

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: You've commented out MySQL standard TCP ports, are you trying to run your script from the same machine MySQL is running?

Comment: yes the script is installed on the same machine, also mysql server is running and i can access to database with commands but the script cannot recognize the path where mysql.sock is stored

Comment: Permissions of /home/mysql/mysql.sock can be a problem.